# Excel - sumifs condition is true but result is 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I try to sum all rows K30:K49 where with the same year and quarter in G30:H49 as in the header G1, G2. My formula is:

```
=SUMIFS(K30:K49;G30:G49;G30*10+H30=G$1*10+G$2)
```

But it returns 0. I tried Evaluation feature and I can see that the condition is evaluated to TRUE. So I expect that it will sum the column K. Where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: This part: `G30*10+H30-1=G$1*10+G$2` will evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE` and since `G30:G49` doesn't appear to contain either `TRUE` or `FALSE` values, the result will always be `0`.

Comment: G30? That is where it says 2020? So why do you in criteria use G30*10+H30-1? That should mean 2020*10+2-1 = 20201. Your Criteria should be what is in range G30:G49 that you want to sum

Comment: I see. How shall I modify it? Some form of sumproduct?

Comment: Sorry for missing rows but the sheet is large. I need to have the same year AND quarter. I copied G30*10+H30-1 from another formula where I needed a numerical comparison. Here I can use old plain comparison of two values from two columns.

Comment: Another option would be resuming your data with Pivot Tables, since you got Years and Quarters...

Comment: Sample data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kbmnqNPucKdE1cnqbh_yP4XJaywwWtKs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your goal to sum all 2020 quater 1, 2020 q 2 and so on?
In that case you need more than one criteria range and criteria.

```
=SUMIFS(K30:K49;G30:G49;G1;H30:H49;G2)
```

This makes sure it's 2020 and q1, or 2020 and q2
(And 2020 q1 should return 0, if this is all the data there is, but q2 should return 27000)

Comment: I shared an example sheet here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kbmnqNPucKdE1cnqbh_yP4XJaywwWtKs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I simplified my assignement. Originally I wanted to add a values from previous quarter but it is too complicated. I would be happy to sum the values from the same quarter.

Comment: If you want a running total then you can in the next cell add +G24, then in the next +H24

Answer (score 1):

In case a Pivot Table could work for you, I made a fake dataset to replicate yours:

[image]

And I have resume the data with a Pivot Table:

[image]

My Pivot Table setup is:

1. ROWS: Year field
2. COLUMNS: Quarter field
3. VALUES: Sum up Values field

Also, if you need an horizontal design, you can do it like in your image with a Pivot Table too, just taking Year field and Quarter Field into Columns Section:

[image]

If you use this second option, and you got Excel 2010 or higher, there is an option called [Repeat item labels in a PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repeat-item-labels-in-a-pivottable-882bdb55-9cdc-4d8d-b531-8e96e41dea31) to repeat all years values, like your original design.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**: Checked your example file. I made a Pivot Table with this setup:

1. ROWS: Source field
2. COLUMNS: Year field and Quarter Field
3. Changed form design to TABULAR
4. Deactivated all SUBTOTALS
5. Activated GRANDS TOTALS **ONLY FOR COLUMNS**
6. In the Pivot Table Options, option *in empty cells show* I said *show a 0*

This is the result, very similar to what you want.

[image]